# leetcode "unique email addresses" question explanation

Tags: python-3.x, indexing, slice

I came across this code on leetcode. How does this line work to remove everything after '+' ?

> local = local[:local.index('+')]

```
class Solution(object):
    def numUniqueEmails(self, emails):
        seen = set()
        for email in emails:
            local, domain = email.split('@')
            if '+' in local:
                local = local[:local.index('+')]
            seen.add(local.replace('.','') + '@' + domain)
        return len(seen)
```

Comment: if you have any questions regarding the code or my explanation, feel free to comment below on my answer. Otherwise, I would appreciate it if you were to mark it as accepted since the answer helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What this code is doing is getting the first and last parts  of an email individually by splitting the email. Example:

```
email = "1234+5678@gmail.com"
//local is now 1234+5678. domain is gmail.com
local, domain = email.split('@')
```

**Now, the next bit of code *(which you specifically asked for in your question)***:

```
if '+' in local:
    local = local[:local.index('+')]
```

What this does is **if `+` is in `local`, it gets the index of that `+` and sets `local` equal to the characters before it**. Otherwise, `local` will remain unchanged. In this case, local will now be `1234` because `local.index('+')` returns `4`. Therefore, `local = local[0:4]` sets `local` equal to the first 4 characters.

The last bit of code:

```
seen.add(local.replace('.','') + '@' + domain)
return len(seen)
```

What this does is replace the `.` character in `local` with an empty character. Then, it adds back the `@` which was originally split as well as the `domain`, which in this example was `gmail.com`. So now, `seen` should equal: `1234@gmail.com`. Then it returns the length of `seen` which is `14`. I hope this answer gave you an understanding of what the code does.